# how GetLocalResourceObject output an HTML string?

Tags: model-view-controller, localization

I stored some html contents in a local resource file.
So it has html tags in it such as p, br, div, etc.
I used `GetLocalResourceObject("myContent")`
to display the content on the page, 
but the page doesnt render it as HTML.

Comment: How _does_ the page render it?

Comment: It renders the raw HTML like this: 
<h2>Title</h2>
<p>Content</p>

Answer (score 0):

It turned out that I overlooked the htmlhelper syntax.
I used <%= %> instead of <%: %>